# Debug Varnish HTTP Purge

Tags: wordpress, varnish, purge

One of the Wordpress blogs I'm giving maintenance is not purging the cache using the plugin **Varnish HTTP Purge**. Whether using Varnish Cache Purge button or when we edit a post.

In order to know the cause of the problem, I would like to know a way to check if the purge request is reaching the Varnish server, maybe using varnishlog command.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/varnish-http-purge/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Varnish 4.0

```
varnishlog -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "PURGE"'
```

Answer (score 6):

Varnish 3.x

```
varnishlog -d -c -m RxRequest:PURGE
```

That will output any of the purges in memory. And without `-d` it will output only current requests:

```
varnishlog -c -m RxRequest:PURGE
```

From `man varnishlog`:

`-d` Process old log entries on startup.  Normally, varnishlog will only process entries which are written to the log after it starts.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as the varnish config limiting purge requests to a certain IP, or set of IPs. I know that my typical varnish configs include:

```
acl purge {
  "127.0.0.1";
  "123.45.67.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
  ....

  if (req.request == "PURGE") {
    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
      error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }   
    return (lookup);
  }

  ....
}
```

I would check that first, especially the config was copied off some examples off the varnish website. Almost all of them include an ACL for purge.